# Detecting whether an external program creates files/forders

Tags: c#, process, detection

I'm building a windows form application, which starts an external program (via process.start etc.) Is there a way to detect whether this external program creates any files/folder, and if so where? 
I've looked into process.StandardOutput, but this doesn't seem to be it (unless ofcourse I'm doing it wrong...)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to read about FileSystemWatcher. Maybe it will helpful.

Comment: Thanks Frank, somebody on another forum [link](http://tinyurl.com/apybelr) suggested that too. However, I can't know beforehand if the external program will produce files/folders, nor where it will create those. I don't really fancy watching my entire filesystem, also because I (or the user) then can't really work when it's running.
Ideally I'd have something that could watch the process to see if files of folders are created by that process.
Wouter

Comment: Interesting problem. I hope solution will be found.

Comment: My hunch is that, no, you will not be able to do this without watching the entire file system.  Now, you could make some assumptions and get a close answer, such as assuming that files will be created in certain shared areas (my documents, for example) or the program that is running's own directory.